# Tensorflow/Keras Type Error about compile

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I import

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

these and at this part,

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam'(lr=0.001), metrics=['acc'])
```

like this Type error was occurred

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-d2bcad9a50e3> in <module>
----> 1 model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam'(lr=0.001), metrics=['acc'])

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I found it on google, but I could not find a solution...
Does anyone know why this error is occurred?
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

change it to this:

```
opt = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Thank you! Do I have to separate it? My teacher use like this "model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=SGD(lr=0.1), metrics=['acc'])" but it works

Comment: no you can have in a single line `model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])`